# PHP merge 2 Json into 1

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 JSON files that I would like to parse, and merge into one object and output as a single JSON.
but I can't figure out how to do and get the correct result, every time i try always get a single result like this :

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Some title for your blog",
        "url": "\/post.php?id=1",
        "image": "https:\/\/example.com\/images\/small\/1.jpg"
    }
]
```

what i need is to call all the 2 json data to 1 json like this one :

```
[
    {
        "Title": "second title for your blog",
        "url": "\/post.php?id=2",
        "image": "https:\/\/example.com\/images\/small\/2.jpg"
    }

    {
        "Title": "second title for your blog",
        "url": "\/post.php?id=2",
        "image": "https:\/\/example.com\/images\/small\/2.jpg"
    }
    {
        "Title": "third title for your blog",
        "url": "\/post.php?id=3",
        "image": "https:\/\/example.com\/images\/small\/3.jpg"
    }

    and so on... till the end of loop
]
```

Here is my code :

```
$requestUrl="http://example.com/json1.php";
$requestUrl1="http://example.com/json2.php";

$data=file_get_contents($requestUrl);
$data1=file_get_contents($requestUrl1);

$array1 = json_decode($data);
$array2 = json_decode($data1);


$wholedata= [];
$i=0;
foreach ($array1 as $array1) {
    $item['Title'] = $array1->title;
    $item['url'] = $array1->url;
}   
foreach ($array2 as $array2) {
    $item['image'] = $array2->image;
}

$wholedata[] = $item;
            $i++;

$json = json_encode($wholedata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: Application/JSON');

echo $json;
```

Here's the json data :

Json 1

```
[
    {
        "title": "first title for your blog",
        "url": "/post.php?id=1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Second title for your blog",
        "url": "/post.php?id=2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Third title for your blog",
        "url": "/post.php?id=3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Fourth title for your blog",
        "url": "/post.php?id=4"
    },
    {
        "title": "Fifth title for your blog",
        "url": "/post.php?id=5"
    }
]
```

Json 2 :

```
[
    {
        "image": "https://example.com/images/small/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://example.com/images/small/2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://example.com/images/small/3.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://example.com/images/small/4.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "https://example.com/images/small/5.jpg"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with objects (as you are currently using), you can use the index of the first array to get the data from the second array.  Then build the output in one go with the components from both objects and add them to your output...

```
$array1 = json_decode($data);
$array2 = json_decode($data1);

$wholedata= [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $itemData) {
    $wholedata[] = ['Title' => $itemData->title,
        'url' => $itemData->url,
        'image' => $array2[$key]->image];
}

$json = json_encode($wholedata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deocoding the json in an array and then merge them. Check out the official PHP documentation

**[array-merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)** - Merges two array

[**json_decode**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - Converts json into an array

Comment: *Try deocoding the json in an array and then merge them* isn't a particularly helpful answer (IMHO).

Comment: Try with array_merge function